# Missing Wordpress theme files and throwing error Warning: include(carousel.php): failed to open stream:

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

My wordpress site showed me the error below last month and I got to discover that the file is no more in the **c-panel** file manager , I actually uploaded the file and it went back normal, now it is showing the same error and now it's two files that have missed , that of the `footer.php` and the `carousel.php`. Please what have I done wrong , what may have deleted the file, I have searched everywhere in the file manager , I have not seen the files.

This is the **error** generated below

```
 Warning: include(carousel.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/romainpk/public_html/wp-content/themes/romancom/index.php on line 61

 Warning: include(): Failed opening 'carousel.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/romainpk/public_html/wp-content/themes/romancom/index.php on line 61
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem are happening because the themes always are updating in any time. I mean, all THE files that you put into your theme folder or any change you do un a file, it will losed with this automatically update-.

For solve this problem, create a Them Child for your theme. The target here is STOP to loosing all THE new files or changes that you are doing in THE original Theme.

Check this INFO FROM the official WordPress site. 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that when you update your theme, it gets the modified settings changed and some files are overwritten or even deleted. It can also happen if some settings on your theme files cause the changes.

If you are not using a child theme and have modified the original theme files, I suggest you to read a recent article about how to [create a WordPress child theme](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/01/create-customize-wordpress-child-theme/) to understand how to get started. Then, you can modify your settings without affecting the original theme files.